# How do I dictate verbally to my PC?

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, voice-command

I have seen examples of people speaking to their computer and it writes down everything they say.  How can I do this with MS office 2007?  Are there any other programs that can also do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/)

Comment: Always makes me think of this http://bash.org/?34776

Answer (score 3):

The SAPI engine built into Windows also will do this.

Answer (score 3):

Windows has built-in speech recognition, at least in vista/windows 7. Just type speech into your start menu.

Comment: Ooooh.  I forsee many wasted hours playing with this.

Answer (score 1):

They moved the speech recognition out of Office 2007 (it was in 2003) and into windows Vista/7